# Do we reply "approve" or "approved" in an approval request email?

Tags: adjectives, correspondence

If you were to approve the following email:

> Dear Tom,
>
> Kindly requesting for your approval on the enclosed content.
>
> Regards,
>   Bob

What would you write?

> 1. Approve.
>      Regards,
>      Tom
> 2. Approved.
>      Regards,
>      Tom

And why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: In a one-word email, I don't think it really matters all that much. Either one of those could show up in my inbox, and I'd just be happy that my request was approved.

Answer (score -1):

This should be:

> Approved.

The full sentence version would be:

> This has now been approved.

This is because it is in the past tense.

Since it's a pretty relaxed environment, there are other replies that would work but this one feels most natural to my (BrE) ear. As @AntonSherwood mentioned 
"it's more natural to read a bare verb as an imperative."

Hence it is past tense.

If you wanted to pad the response out a bit, you could say something like:

> You have [got] my approval.

Comment: Hello, Bee. Why can't the full sentence be 'I approve this'?

Comment: As soon as you send the email, it's in the past. Therefore saying you approve this (although grammatically correct) doesn't feel right, since the person reading the email will read it after the fact.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Because it's more natural to read a bare verb as an imperative.

Comment: @Anton Sherwood I'm almost certain I've come across the usage, possibly the impression of an old rubber stamp, though I'd agree that the past participle seems more natural here. But on ELU, this question would probably be regarded as 'primarily opinion based' (ie we're really guessing: are we to assume that business jargon mirrors well-behaved English so closely?) This answer also lacks any supporting evidence for the claimed correct answer, which would be seen as another problem on ELU. Perhaps that's not the case here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have not provided supporting evidence as it seems to me that this is a pretty straight forward question. I have stated about that I do believe that the other response is valid, however would not be common. In any case, I do not believe that OP is looking for an answer which conforms to "proper English", since he is looking to reply with a one word response. It is a unique situation which I believe a source will be difficult to find. I have given a valid reason for my response, which I believe to be sufficient. Feel free to flag the post if you disagree.

Comment: I think that your extrapolation of a sentence from one word needs more explanation incorporated into your answer. I could respond to that e-mail with “I approve.” Or “I have approved.” Maybe you could find some real-world examples even though it’s difficult to find a reference? I have an email from the head of our group that responded to a similar request with “I approve.” so I don’t think it’s as straightforward as you feel it is. (I’m trying to help you improve your answer, not trying to make you feel criticized. You don’t have to change a thing if you’re happy with your answer)

Comment: How's about **It's OK. You got/have my approval**?

Comment: @Gamora Writing in the past tense because a message will be read in the future does not make sense. You'd write "I am fine today" if writing e-mail to your friend, not "I was fine"!

Answer (score -2):

Approved is the right one If the request has been approved already while replying to the email

Comment: And what if the email itself _is_ the approval?

Comment: We're looking for answers with more detail than this. Imagine that some other anonymous person writes the exact opposite -- how would anybody know who to believe?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners, and thanks for your answer. This answer was flagged by the system because it's so short, so please allow me to give you some tips as a brand new user. The community here values answers that are well thought-out and provide detail that helps the learner improve their knowledge and use of the English Language. I don't think this answer meets those criteria. As it is it's in danger of being voted down. Please look around at other answers with a lot of votes to see what's expected. You're welcome to edit your answer if you can make it better.